# can't pass the values to other activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to intent this form activity to my other activity, but i already checked it and I don't know what is wrong in this.

```
                Sname_i = Sname.getText().toString();
                Fname_i = Fname.getText().toString();
                Mname_i = Mname.getText().toString();
                Type = Bloodtype.getText().toString();
                Color = Eyecolor.getText().toString();
                Birthdate = Dob.getText().toString();
                Birthplace = Pob.getText().toString();
                Address_i = Address.getText().toString();

                int selected_gender = radiogroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                radiobtn = findViewById(selected_gender);
                gender = radiobtn.getText().toString();

                Intent i;
                i = new Intent(form.this, MainActivity.class);

                i.putExtra("Sname", Sname_i);
                i.putExtra("Fname", Fname_i);
                i.putExtra("Mname", Mname_i);
                i.putExtra("bloodtype", Type);
                i.putExtra("eyecolor", Color);
                i.putExtra("Bd", Birthdate);
                i.putExtra("Bp", Birthplace);
                i.putExtra("Add", Address_i);
                i.putExtra("gender", gender);

                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

here is my other activity java that i want it to get the values from my form activity. it only shows the main activity when i run it in my emulator

```
        Sname = intent.getStringExtra("Sname");
        Fname = intent.getStringExtra("Fname");
        Mname = intent.getStringExtra("Mname");
        names = Sname + " " + Fname + " " + Mname + " ";
        type = intent.getStringExtra("bloodtype");
        color = intent.getStringExtra("eyecolor");
        Birthdate = intent.getStringExtra("Bd");
        Birthplace = intent.getStringExtra("Bp");
        address_i = intent.getStringExtra("Add");
        gender_i = intent.getStringExtra("gender");

        name.setText(names);
        Dob.setText(Birthdate);
        gender.setText(gender_i);
        Pob.setText(Birthplace);
        Address.setText(address_i);
        bloodtype.setText(type);
        eyecolor.setText(color);

    }
}
```

Comment: can you please provide a minimal example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Can you please provide what you got here, any error? , any data?

Comment: MainActivity is usually the activity that is started when you open the app. If you want your app to start on another activity you will have to make changes into the Manifest.
Also as mentioned above, please provide more details on your implementation